# Calculating the distance between two articles accurately

Tags: php, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I am writing a software to compare articles. I am looking for an efficient and accurate algorithm to calculate the difference (variation) between two articles. The variation should completely depend on words and not letters. I have tried `levenshtein()` but it has a time complexity of **O(n*m)** which is very expensive when performed on big texts like an article. I have also tried  `similar_text()` which has a higher time complexity of **O(n*m*3)**. Moreover, `levenshtein()` and `similar_text()` calculates the number of operations needed to transform one string to another which is not an accurate way to calculate the difference between two big articles.

What other options do I have?

---

**EDIT:**

I am trying to calculate the variation approximately from the point of view of a search engine (Google).

Comment: This is a worthwhile problem, and not a simple one. I would start by getting familiar with [*biological sequence comparison*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC280013/pdf/pnas00260-0036.pdf) Then I would try to think about how to define my distance metric: what kinds of alterations would I allow? how would I handle different spellings? etc.

Comment: @deadlock, need more context here. What do you consider to be variation? Are you looking at subject matter? Writing style? Sentiment? Or are you looking to identify statistically significant blocks that indicate plagiarism?

Comment: @richard A variation is just a different word than the original. Its that simple

Comment: word or character?  word means they need to be tok first?

Comment: @deadlock that doesn't sound simple to me :) To catch additions/subtractions you'd need to fingerprint segments of text and track their movement. Doing that algorithmically isn't simple. In absence of any context about why you're doing this or what you hope to achieve, your best bet is probably to compare the documents statistically, using TF/IDF or similar. Suggest looking at Lucene's MLT implementation (MoreLikeThis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I needed to calculate the variation between two articles. So, I found that very simple solution working for me very well. It works by simply calculating the similarity as the **common words** between the two articles divided by ***max(number of words in article A, number of words in article B)***. The variation then is calculated by subtracting the similarity from 100 to get the variation percentage. The code below explains it all.

```
function get_variation($article1,$article2){

      $wordsA = array_unique(preg_split('@[\W]+@', $article1));
      $wordsB = array_unique(preg_split('@[\W]+@', $article2));
      $intersection = array_intersect($wordsA, $wordsB);
      $similarity = (count($intersection)/ (max(count($wordsA),count($wordsB))) * 100);
      $similarity =  number_format($similarity, 2, '.', '');
      $variation = 100-$similarity;
      return $variation;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL uses a [tsvector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-textsearch.html) for it's full-text search feature. Maybe that's something that could get quite handy for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can define how to measure text similarity based on words, you are half way through. For example: You may count the occurence of each word for both article and then create a simple difference of the two lists. However, this does not work for similarity by meaning.

If you have a database, use their fulltext features. As mentioned before, PostGres offers such a feature. I work with MSSQL and you could simply call the FREETEXT function which will calculate a 'rank' indicating how similar two texts are.

I highly recommend using a mature product, instead of trying to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to compare two articles. `levenshtein()` and `similar_text()` designed to compare two words, not articles.

The simplest algorythm is to explode your articles by words, find word-by-word similaryty and do some math, depending on your task, like this:

```
// not tested!
function similar_articles($articleA, $articleB) {
  $wordsA = array_unique(preg_split('@[\W]+@', $articleA));
  $wordsB = array_unique(preg_split('@[\W]+@', $articleA));
  $resultSimilarity = 0;
  foreach($wordsA as $wordA) {
    $wordSimilarity = 0;
    foreach($wordsB as $wordB) {
      similar_text($wordA, $wordB, $percent);
      $wordSimilarity = max($wordSimilarity, $percent);
    }
    $resultSimilarity += $wordSimilarity;
  }
  return($resultSimilarity / count($wordsA));
}
```

Note: `similar_articles($artileA, $articleB)` != `similar_articles($artileB, $articleA)` because of `similar_text($wordA, $wordB)` != `similar_text($wordB, $wordA)`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for calculate a type of distance is to compare references. Another method is to select some key word in concordance to a dictionary and calculate the distance in order of social relevance.

Also, in order to use [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) take a look on [stringmetric](http://rockymadden.com/stringmetric/).